# Face matching after detection by photo

Tags: ios, opencv

Looking for a way to match images. User uploads an image to a web server; server compares to a database or folder of images and indicates if a match was found. Will never be an exact pixel for pixel match think face-matching photos.

Answer (score 0):

For face matching, pixel-based matching won't work well. google for "Eigen Faces", it is a technique which matches faces by the most distinguishable features.